# Insert statement cx_Oracle

Tags: cx-oracle

I am new to cx_Oracle and working on a project using Python3, and getting some errors. Here is my code:

```
    uemail="jack@gmail.com"
    uname="Jack"
    upassword="asdasd"
    cursInsert=connection.cursor()
    insert_stat="insert into users(email,name,pass,last_login) values (:uemail,:uname,:upassword,NULL)"
    cursInsert.execute(insert_stat)
    connection.commit()
    cursInsert.close()
```

Here is the error message that I get:  not all variables bound

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass values to the bind variables for oracle like this

```
cursInsert.execute(insert_stat, uemail=uemail, uname=uname, upassword=upassword)
```